# Prove $\sqrt {92}$ is an irrational number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, irrational-numbers

Prove $\sqrt {92}$ is an irrational number is the question. I know how to do questions like root $4$ etc., however I do not know how to go about this any help is appreciated! This is what I have so far.

In order to prove $\sqrt {92}$ is irrational, we must use proof by contradiction. Hence we must first
prove it isn’t rational. In order to prove $\sqrt {92}$ is rational, we must see if it can be written as the
ratio of 2 co-prime integers $a$ and $b$ such that $a/b= \sqrt {92}$ and $a, b$ are no longer reducible.
By squaring both sides, we get:

$92=a^2/b^2 \\
92b^2=a^2$

Therefore $a^2$ is an even number as anything multiplied by $92$ is an even number
Therefore $a$ is even as $a \times a$ is even.
Therefore $\sqrt {92}$ is irrational.

Comment: $92=4\times 23$$

Comment: Wouldn't your "proof" also demonstrate that $\sqrt 4$ is irrational (which isn't true, of course)?  Note that $\sqrt{92} =2 \sqrt{23}$.  Do you know how to prove $\sqrt 2$ is irrational?  Can you generalize that proof to show that $\sqrt p$ is irrational for any prime $p$?

Comment: It would be easier to craft a helpful response if Readers were told your math background.  At a more advanced level of studies one learns that for positive integer $n$, the square root $\sqrt n$ is rational only when it is a whole number.

Comment: So what if $a^2$ is even?  Why would that make $\sqrt{92}$ irrational?....  After all if  $\sqrt{100} =\frac ab$ then $100=\frac {a^2}{b^2}$ so $100b^2 = a^2$.  So $a^2$ is even and so $a$ is an even number and.... so what? That doesn't mean $\sqrt{100}$ is irrational.

Comment: $a^2$ is even.  Not only even but divisible by $4$.  But that's not a contradiction so long as $b$ is odd.  The evenness of $a$ is not a problem.  After all,  $92 = 4\cdot 23$ so $\sqrt{92} = \sqrt{4 \cdot 23}$.  It's not the $\sqrt 4$ that's going to be a problem.  It's the $\sqrt{23}$ that is going to be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As $\sqrt{92}=2\sqrt{23}$, it suffices to prove for $23$, which is a prime.

Let $\sqrt{p}=\dfrac ab$ where $a,b$ are relative primes. Then $pb^2=a^2$ and $a^2$ is a multiple of $p$ and it must also be a multiple of $p^2$. Then $b^2$ is a multiple of $p$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

> Therefore a2 is an even number as anything multiplied by 92 is an even number Therefore a is even as a×a is even.

True.  $a^2$ is even.  But.... so what?  So long as $b^2$ is odd we have no contradiction.

So you have $92b^2 = a^2$ where $a$ is even.

Let $a = 2a'$ so $a^2 = 4a'^2$.

We have $92b^2 = 4a'^2$ which means $23b^2 = a'^2$.

That's not at all  a contradiction.

Yet.

But this means $23|a'^2$.  Could that be an issue?

Well, $23$ is prime so if $23|a'^2$ then $23|a$.... so can you finish?

If $23|a'$ then let's let $a'= 23\alpha$.

Then $23b^2 = a'^2 = (23\alpha)^2 = 23^2 \alpha^2$.

So if we divide both sides by $23$ we have

$b^2 = 23 \alpha^2$.

So $23|b^2$.  And as $23$ is prime $23|b$.

.... and !*THAT*! is a problem.  We assumed $a,b$ were coprime.  But we have $23|\alpha$ (so $23|a$) and we have $23|b$.  Well, that contradicts they are coprime.

Answer (score -1):

Your approach is a good one.

From $92b^2 = a^2$, you have that

$23|a^2 \implies 23|a \implies $

[since $a,b$ assumed coprime] $(23)$ does not divide $(b)$.

Therefore, you have that

$(23)^2$ divides $(a^2)$ but $(23)^2$ does not divide $92b^2$.

This is your contradiction.